# Are treasure maps broken in Minecraft 1.19?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

As far as I know, buried treasure, in Bedrock edition, are always hidden in the <8,y,8> block of the pointed chunk, and up to 1.18 I knew where I had to dig. But this is not always true in 1.19.

This is my third treasure map with an (apparently) missing treasure. They are unusual also because the red cross is in the middle of the land, not on a beach or a piece of water. If I dig straight below I reach the bedrock, so something isn't working as expected.

Is buried treasures generation broken in 1.19?